# Compute Union (Set) of arrays while maintaining order

Tags: arrays, f#

I've spent enough time trying to solve this problem and i could not. 
I have this arrays:

```
   let A= [|1;2;3;4;5|]
   let B= [|3;4;5;6;7;8|]
```

and I want make the union of these arrays without repeated elements appear

```
   let C=[|1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8|]
```

I think with Array.append A B, but I can't remove the repeated elements.

Comment: If the ordering doesn't matter, drop the requirement I added to the title.

Comment: I don't use F#, but LINQ has the [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx) method, which can be used for this (after appending the sequences). I suspect there is a more-F#-way though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, if you want to create a collection only containing distinct elements you probably should consider using a [`Set`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353619.aspx) instead.

```
let A = [|1;2;3;4;5|]
let B = [|3;4;5;6;7;8|]

let C = Set(A) + Set(B) 
// 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8
```

Alternatively, using [`Seq.concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353462.aspx) and [`Seq.distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353698.aspx) will do essentially the same thing, but return a `seq`:

```
let C = [ A ; B ] 
        |> Seq.concat 
        |> Seq.distinct
```

Now with either of these solutions, if you want to turn this back to an array just use [`Seq.toArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340263.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
let A = [|1;2;3;4;5|]
let B = [|3;4;5;6;7;8|]
let C = Set.ofArray A + Set.ofArray B :> seq<_>
```